# Error while android development studio setup

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to install android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows.exe on my machine. Below is the configuration:

1. Windows 7 64 bit
2. JDK7 Update 67 with JAVA_HOME variable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried many suggestions stated but I am unable to install. Below screenshots will show the steps I am following and the errors I am getting during installation.

Step 1: Start installation using exe

Error 1: Click ignore

[image]

Error 2: Click ignore

[image]

Error 3: Click ignore

[image]

Step 2: Click Next

[image]

Step 3: Click Browse to select JDK directory

[image]

Error 4: No directory structure shown

[image]

Step 4: Manually add JDK location in the text box

[image]

Error 4: Click Next. Error

[image]

Please help me to solve if anyone has encountered such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a breakthrough to this problem. I have McAfee antivirus installation on my machine which was blocking creation or extraction of .exe file on C drive. I have disabled antivirus for the time being so that I could install android studio.